# Creating an array of graphic paths in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, path, system.drawing, graphicspath

I dont know Why I am having trouble with this, but I keep getting 'not set to an instance of an object' exception every time.

Does this make sense?

I have this declared in the main form

```
Private _Paths() As System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
```

and do this in a sub

```
 _Paths(20) = New GraphicsPath
```

But for whatever reason I get an object reference error on the second line. Any help?

After the decleration, I want to then go ahead and add a line to the graphics path like so

```
 _Paths(k).AddLine(x_loc(k), y_loc(k), x_loc(k + 1), y_loc(k + 1))
```

As per suggestion to use list:

Declared in main class

```
Private _Paths As List(Of System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)
```

using in sub

```
for k = 0 to 10
      'x_loc and y_loc calculations are done here

    _Paths.Add(New GraphicsPath)
    _Paths(k).AddLine(x_loc(k), y_loc(k), x_loc(k + 1), y_loc(k + 1))
next
```

still get error when trying to create new instance of graphicspath

There should be no reason this error should pop up right?
[image]

```
Private _Paths As NEW List(Of System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not redimensioning your array, instead use a `List(Of GraphicsPath)` and just `.Add` them as you need.

```
Dim myPaths As New List(Of GraphicsPath)
'later in code
myPaths.Add(New GraphicsPath)
myPaths(0).AddLine(...)'etc...
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how I would use the list. Right now after declaring the graphics path I do


     _Paths(k).AddLine(x_loc(k), y_loc(k), x_loc(k + 1), y_loc(k + 1)

how would I add that to a list?

Comment: You add a new GraphicsPath whenever you need to, then you can still access them by index like above. You just need to figure out when that happens.

Comment: Thanks. I havent used lists much. I still seems to be getting a not set to an instance, except at the line

_Paths.Add(New GraphicsPath)

Comment: That is weird, I have attached a picture of a test I ran. Do you mind taking a look? It should just add those?

Comment: Got it, forgot to put the 'New'.

Thanks a lot for the help :D

Comment: You have to declare your list as `New`. Look at the code again.

Answer (score 1):

A list must be declared with New

```
Dim YourList As New List(Of GraphicsPath)
```

I notice in your screenshot you are not actually adding new GraphicsPath objects
You are not giving the parameters to create one

```
Dim Rec As New Rectangle(LocationX,LocationY, Width,Height) 'Create a binding rectangle to contain the graphic
Yourlist.Add(New GraphicsPath {Rec}) 'In place of 'Rec' you can also specify parameters directly
```

OR

```
Yourlist.Add(New GraphicsPath {LocationX,LocationY, Width,Height})
```